# jQuery Nested Response Array Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a function that authenticates a username/password:

Here is the JSON RESPONSE:

`{"data":{"user_id":"2","auth_token":"x"},"result":  {"errorcode":"","messages":"Success:Logged On","rstatus":1}}`

I want to be able to parse out the user_id, auth_token, errorcode, messages, rstatus

Here is the JQuery code that is invoked:

```
function authenticate(userName, password) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?action=login',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: 'username=' + userName + '&password=' + password,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            //i need to parse out the data here
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help you in future. Please read it thoroughly.. [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var user_id = response.data.user_id, 
    auth_token = response.data.auth_token, 
    errorcode = response.result.errorcode, 
    messages = response.result.messages, 
    rstatus = response.result.rstatus;
```

Comment: errorcode, messages and rstatus are from `response.result`. :P

Comment: @Vega -- Bah, should've checked that, looked at the JSON to quickly :P

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
var user_id = response.data.user_id,
   auth_token = response.data.auth_token,
   errorcode = response.result.errorcode,
   messages = response.result.messages,
   rstatus = response.result.rstatus;
```